# Redirecting original c# program output to Xunit output

Tags: c#, xunit

Is there a way to redirect the **original** program output to XUnit output?

All i could find is how to print output from XUnit tests (see [here](https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output))

With "original output" i mean that for each time i write `Console.WriteLine` or similar in my program i want that output to be there when i look at test results.

I know that it is possible to redirect console output to a different textwriter ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setout?view=netcore-3.1)), how can i set up my tests so that all output is redirected to Xunit?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little work but it is achievable.

Like you mentioned, you came across `ITestOutputHelper`.  With a bit more effort, you can redirect the `Console` output to a new class that implements the `TextWriter`.

So from this, if you put together something like:

```
public class RedirectOutput : TextWriter
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper _output;

    public RedirectOutput(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        _output = output;
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding { get; } // set some if required

    public override void WriteLine(string? value)
    {
        _output.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

And in you test constructor (which I suspect the piece you are missing?):

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    public UnitTest1(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        Console.SetOut(new RedirectOutput(output));
    }

    ...
}
```

This is where we are doing a redirect from the `Console` to `ITestOutputHelper` .

The downside of this is that you will NEED to override EVERY use of a `Console`.Write call you use in your code.  So `RedirectOutput` can end up quite large.  See [ms docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netcore-3.1) for a list overloads.

I don't know of any other way - I would have hoped it would be simpler.   Surely there is another solution somewhere.

But at least this will get you going, if you havent already.

Also might be worth a rethink of design around using Console writes in your code.  Perhaps something around a custom interface output?